# Notification light when turning on phone

Tags: notification-led

currently I'm running 6.01 on a 2013 Nexus 5, with Xposed installed.

This is purely for aesthetic purposes; however, is it possible to have the notification LED flash when I turn the phone on (some newer LG phones do this).

Is there a way to call a script when you press the power button?

Comment: I think that requires modification at kernel level...

Comment: Try [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) .*Trigger* Screen on,; *Action* Notification LED enable. My device didn't have notification light to test

Comment: What do you mean by turning the phone on? Do you mean restarting/powering on the phone or simply waking up the device? For the former, you would need a kernel with support for init scripts.

Comment: @beeshyams Tried MacroDroid. Unfortunately, it simply enables the notification light.

Comment: @Firelord Is there a trigger for the screen backlight on/power button, and is there a way I can power on the notification light, preferably via an .sh script? My phone is rooted with the latest EX kernel.